# ZK get value of a HTML input

Tags: html, zk

I want to get a value of a HTML text input in my ViewModel :

```
                <div class="InputAddOn"
                visible="@bind(vm.resetPasswordEmailDiv)">
                <h:input class="InputAddOn-field"
                    name="resetPasswordEmail" id="resetPasswordEmail"
                    disabled="@bind(vm.resetPasswordEmailDisabled)"
                    value="@bind(vm.resetPasswordEmail)"/>
                <button class="InputAddOn-item"
                    onClick="@command('sendResetPasswordEmail')">
                    Send
                </button>
            </div>
```

So when I click on the send button I get the value in my `@Command` method.

Here even the `value="@bind(vm.resetPasswordEmail)"` dosen't work

Comment: Can you show us the corresponding code in your ViewModel ?

Comment: Does the binding for `disabled` work? You could try to pass the input value as a [BindingParam in the command binding](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/Advanced/Parameters#A_Local_Command_Example).

Comment: and how can I get the value of the input to pass it as a bindingParam ?

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code and the binding worked just fine. Below you find an example that uses both the binding and the [command parameter](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/Advanced/Parameters#A_Local_Command_Example):

```
<div xmlns:h="xhtml" viewModel="@id('vm')@init('somePath.MyViewModel')">
    <h:input value="@bind(vm.bindingParam)" />
    <button label="Send" onClick="@command('doCommand', commandParam=self.previousSibling.value)" />
</div>

public class MyViewModel
{
    String bindingParam;

    public String getBindingParam()
    {
        return bindingParam;
    }

    public void setBindingParam(String bindingParam)
    {
        this.bindingParam = bindingParam;
    }

    @Command
    public void doCommand(@BindingParam("commandParam") String commandParam)
    {
        System.out.println(bindingParam + " " + commandParam);
    }
}
```

When you click the button, it will output `null null` or `myText myText` according to the content of the input.

Retrieving the text from the input is done with the same expression language as the bindings. `self` is the replacement for `this`, and I used `getPreviousSibling` but you should be able to use IDs, too.